# Can not validate XML

Tags: java, spring, maven, apache-camel

I am trying to create a camel route in spring boot. I get the following error.

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw '301 Moved Permanently'.

My applicationContext.xml looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws" 
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" 
    xmlns:camelcxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
    xmlns:http-conf="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
           http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
           http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
             http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
             http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/jaxws.xsd
             http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/core.xsd"
    default-activation="lazy">

        <!--  CXF SERVER  -->
    <camelcxf:rsServer id="productRestController"
        address="http://0.0.0.0:8080/product"
        serviceClass="com.born.oktopus.product.controller.ProductRestController"
        loggingFeatureEnabled="true" loggingSizeLimit="20" >

        <!-- <cxf:schemaLocations> <value>classpath:/schemas/productDataList.xsd</value> 
            </cxf:schemaLocations> <camelcxf:providers> <ref component-id="jaxbProviderXsi" 
            /> </camelcxf:providers> -->

    </camelcxf:rsServer>

    <!--  ERP BEANS -->
    <bean id="loggingOutInterceptor" 
                 class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" >
        <property name="prettyLogging" value="true" />
    </bean>



</blueprint>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to validate a transformation file with an XML file instead of an XSD as the applicationContext.xml appears correct.

You need to show us the JAVA code where you are parsing with SAX, but I would guess you either have a typo of some kind or you are thinking you are parsing the XSD file, but you reference the XML file.